# Passing Lists Between Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Creating a simple notification system that redirects the user to a notifications page on login if they have any new notifications.

I am getting the notification data in the login method and adding all the notifications to a list. I then want to pass this list to another action in a different controller to do some logic there so i can leave my login controller as untouched as possible. The problem is the list will not pass in a redirectToAction so i need to use tempdata apparently.

the list i am trying to pass is a object list

```
List<Notificaions> = new List<Notifications>();

// populate list.

      if (notifications.Count > 0)
        {
         TempData["notifications"] = notifications;
          return RedirectToAction("notification", "main");
       }
```

And Then My Notfication Action

```
  public ActionResult Notification ()
   {
       List<NotificationViewModel> notifications = new List<Notifications>();
       notifications = TempData["notifications"];
   }
```

I need to figure out how to convert the tempdata back into a object list. Can someone help out please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast `TempData["notifications"]` to `List<NotificationViewModel>` :

```
public ActionResult Notification ()
{
    List<NotificationViewModel> notifications = new List<Notifications>();
    notifications = (List<NotificationViewModel>)TempData["notifications"];
}
```